# Does a MCU come flashed with drivers?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, pcb-design, stm32

I am designing a PCB for which I have made a POC on Arduino. On Arduino it is very simple to flash the program I have written via the IDE.
I have made a bare minimum schematic for the device which will be used in the first iteration of the product.
Now I ask this question in hopes of understanding.
Are there specific ports to which I should add the JTAG or something to flash the drivers onto the MCU?
Or will it come pre-flashed which would just mean that I have to solder the MCU the correct way onto the PCB with the passive components connect the entire set-up to the Arduino IDE for example if I use the ATmega386 and it will show up?

This question comes more from trying to understand how the MCU is made, the TTL layout of the MCU, since we were buying a bare board and I am responsible for flashing it, I wanted to make sure that the right ports were used.

Comment: you need **bootloader** befor writing any sketchh to MCU .take a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62rhbh9_GKw

Comment: This question is currently *too broad* to fit here both in its scope and in that the only specific part it mentions is one that does not even exist.  Before designing a custom board, you need to better familiarize yourself with the MCU to be utilized, by taken time to really *understand* how it is utilized on an evaluation board.

Comment: Do you want me to remove this question or what?

Comment: It depends on the MCU and possibly where you are buying it from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The microcontroller will not come pre-flashed with Arduino firmware.

There are specific pins that are intended to be connected to an in-circuit programmer which in turn plugs into your computer through USB.

Read the datasheet/manual to find out what they are. And be very, very careful and thorough here. One mistake here can junk the entire board.

The microcontroller might come pre-loaded with a bootloader, in which case you need to find out what the startup pin configuration is, and what the protocol is, what pins are used, and what you need to do at the PC end to work with it.

Comment: And all of this is in the datasheet?

Comment: So if I am getting this right PCIDE=>USB Cable=>USB Port on PCB=>Specific Pins on MCU. This connection will flash the MCU with my firmware. Where PCIDE will be a specific software operated from the terminal to flash a particular firmware? Do you have a reference video or an article?

Comment: @ShridharSharma It should be somewhere from the manufacturer. It may be under different terms that you are used to in the manual or datasheet. It is PCIDE->USB Cable->USB In-circuit Programmer/JTAG ->Wire->Specific Pins on MCU. The PC software used depends on the Programmer/JTAG used. It may be standalone software to upload the binary or it may also integrate into the IDE.